# Changing the value of a Model.Element serverside is not showing in the View()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-core

I use a ViewModel to allow user's to enter all kind of Filterdata and then execute them.
In certain cases I need to chnge the values at serverside and return the View with those changed data. Sounds simple ;)

Here is where the magic stops: I cannot get the changed data to appear in the View.

**This is the View:**

```
@model DrieHamersV4.ViewModels.FilterListVM
@using DrieHamersV4.Helpers;
    
<form asp-action="CreateMailingList" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
         <input asp-for="FRoepnaam" class="form-control" placeholder="@Html.DisplayNameFor(c => Model.FRoepnaam)" />
          <label asp-for="FRoepnaam"></label>                                   
    </div>
    <div>
        <input asp-for="FAchternaam" class="form-control" placeholder="@Html.DisplayNameFor(c => Model.FAchternaam)" />
        <label asp-for="FAchternaam"></label>
    </div>                                           
    <div>
         <div>@ViewBag.Random</div>                        
    <div>
         <button type="submit">Apply Filter</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**This is the Controller**

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateMailingList(FilterListVM mailingList)
    {
        // all fields to use as filters
        // 
        // 
        string fFirstName = mailingList.FRoepnaam;
        string fLastName = mailingList.FAchternaam;            
        
        // Testing if the new number `num` will appear in  View()
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int num = rnd.Next(0, 100);
        
        mailingList.FAchternaam = num.ToString(); // When loading works, but not after renewing View()
        ViewBag.Random = (num.ToString()); //Works fine
        
        return View(mailingList);
    }
```

One way or another the View() refers back to the values when it initially loaded. Changing the values at the clientside works just fine. Changing them at the serverside, however is the problem. The View uses the model `@model DrieHamersV4.ViewModels.FilterListVM` 
I am sure I am missing something obvious. Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by "reloading"? Generally the pattern is to have a GET method to 'create' a view and a POST method to accept data from a form (via a ViewModel). Which one are we looking at (I assume POST)? Can you show the code of the view and of the other controller method (GET, if my assumption was correct). To make it easier to get to the error, can you reduce your sample code to the minimum necessary to reproduce the error (basically your assigning a random string to `mailingList.FAchternaam` which then is not shown in the view; everything else is distraction).

Comment: Have you tried added  ModelState.Clear();

Comment: What is your Model.Element ?Besides , how you chang the value of a Model.Element serverside and what do you mean  you want to show them in the `View()`?  Do you mean return `View(mailingList);` ?  What is fFirstName ?  the  Model.Element  or   changed data? If  `fFirstName` is changed data, what's the value of it? If  `fFirstName`  is  Model.Element  , belong to which model? Could you share that model code?

Comment: Probably you are not posting the data back when reloading the view. Are you doing a post call by submitting the existing data? show the view file as well.

Comment: @JürgenRöhr: I have added the View. With reloading I mean: After the View (form) is submitted, it shpould come back with a changed random number.

Comment: @RajeshG I just tried the same with the Post method in the Form. Result remains the same however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change a value at serverside of a Model element, you must include a **value taghelper** in your input-element. An **asp-for taghelper** does not suffice. I have changed the View accordingly. However, I do not know *why* it works.

```
@model DrieHamersV4.ViewModels.FilterListVM
@using DrieHamersV4.Helpers;

<form asp-action="CreateMailingList" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
         <input asp-for="FRoepnaam" value="@Model.FRoepnaam" class="form-control" placeholder="@Html.DisplayNameFor(c => Model.FRoepnaam)" />
          <label asp-for="FRoepnaam"></label>                                   
    </div>
    <div>
        <input asp-for="FAchternaam" value="@Model.FAchternaam" class="form-control" placeholder="@Html.DisplayNameFor(c => Model.FAchternaam)" />
        <label asp-for="FAchternaam"></label>
    </div>                                       
    
     <div>@ViewBag.Random</div>                        
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Apply Filter</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Will this not throw NullException when Model is null?

Comment: When the model is empty, all runs well

Answer (score 0):

From your form you're calling `CreateMailingList` instead of `CreateFilterList`.

Comment: Sorry!! My mistake. This was a typo in the question. I have corrected the question.

Comment: I just tried the same with the Post method in the Form. Result remains the same however.